# Exchange method in RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring

hi i have a problem and i need help, im using the next code

```
ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity =
        restTemplate.exchange(someUrlString, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class);
```

and the java console show me this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
```

I have been debugging 2 hours and I think the error is in the parameter Resource.class that is passed to the exchange() method.

Comment: 404 means, the requested resource is not found at the URL endpoint. Please check your 'someUrlString' and verify whether you have a resource present at the url or not

Comment: Is it your service or someone's you refer to?

Comment: Any `GET` responce could be tested with browser. If it gets 404 too, there is server problem. Or problem with url.

Comment: The 'someUrlString' is this: http://localhost:8085/services/server-attachment/download/alfresco/workspace/SpacesStore/bb832131-4554-4bf4-be62-8879c478e52b/dcd5e73a-ae51-e711-8108-5065f38aea61_caratula.png

Comment: Sounds like the local server you are running isn't running anymore or there is a mistyped resource. Was it working at one point? What service are you trying to run?

Comment: The local server is running. I know it because other files was downloaded. Maybe the problems is a mistyped resource. Tnx to all

Comment: Hello again.
I think the error happens when read the 'sameUrlString', maybe is caused by the chars like '_' or like '-'. 
We put a GUID for do unique the register of the file in the Data Base, and we cant change this guid in the name of file.
some idea?